# Combine two (or more) Phalcon models to one query

Tags: php, orm, phalcon

I have two models **(I'm using Phalcon PHP Framework).**

For saving them, I have to use `$model->save()` function, but that would create two queries.

I would like to save them but only use one query.
How can that be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What is your issue? With "Raw SQL", to Insert/Update 2 tables, your still have to use 2 queries.